# Javascript convert from string number to integer

Tags: javascript, excel, string, date, integer

I am creating an excel date format while I using JavaScript but I got stuck about convert string to integer.

```
function getCurrentDateFormat (date,errorValue, removeSecond, clientTimeZoneOffset) {

    if (date !== undefined && date !== null) {
        const currDate = new Date(date)

        const currDay = currDate.getDate()
        const currMonth = currDate.getMonth()
        const currYear = currDate.getFullYear()
        const currHour = currDate.getHours().toString().padStart(2,0)
        const currMinutes = currDate.getMinutes()
        const currSeconds = currDate.getSeconds()

        return currDay + "/" + currMonth + 1 + "/" + currYear + " " + currHour + ":" + currMinutes + ":" + currSeconds
 
    }
    else {
        return errorValue
    }

}
```

This function give me this result : 30/01/2024 9:27:24

I want to make hour like 09. When I try to make integer zero(0) disappear. How can fix this situation?

Comment: no it doesn't - it produces `09` ... by the way ... in february, the month will show as 11, in march it'll be 21, in april it'll be 31 - can you see an issue with that?

Comment: the integer does not have the leading zero. You just need to convert it to an integer and then use excel to format it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try the following

```
var s = "0" + currHour;
var hr= s.substr(s.length-2);

return currDay + "/" + currMonth + 1 + "/" + currYear + " " + hr + ":" + 
currMinutes + ":" + currSeconds;
```

Comment: or just `currHour.toString().padStart(2, "0")`

Comment: just const currHour = currDate.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0") solves

Comment: and yet, still the month will be wrong for every month except january :p